# openapi-generator /maven plugin generates invalid java code with «, » characters

Tags: java, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I just migrating my code from swagger-code generator to open-api code generator. I am using the generator through the [maven plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin). I need it to generate a client for an external API (outside my control), the used swagger file is given.

my plugin setting is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <supportingFiles>
                        ApiClient.java,Authentication.java,OAuth.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,RFC3339DateFormat.java
                    </supportingFiles>
                </environmentVariables>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api-tpz.json</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <configOptions>
                    <library>resttemplate</library>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To have a minimal example i stripped down the source of swagger to:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "Api Documentation",
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "Api Documentation",
        "termsOfService": "urn:tos",
        "contact": {

        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
        }
    },
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "basicAuth": {
            "type": "basic"
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
            "basicAuth": []
        }
    ],
    "host": "example.com",
    "basePath": "/api",
    "tags": [
    ],
    "paths": {
    },
    "definitions": {
        "GenericRow": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "GenericRow",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        },
        "ResultList«GenericRow»": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "offset": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "overallCount": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/GenericRow"
                    }
                }
            },
            "title": "ResultList«GenericRow»"
        }
    }
}
```

While the generator runs fine the code is invalid

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    ResultListGenericRow resultList«GenericRow» = (ResultListGenericRow) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.offset, resultList«GenericRow».offset) &&
        Objects.equals(this.overallCount, resultList«GenericRow».overallCount) &&
        Objects.equals(this.results, resultList«GenericRow».results);
  }
```

`resultList«GenericRow»` is just wrong.

On the other hand the name of the **Class is generated correctly** `ResultListGenericRow` only variable names are handled wrong.

How to fix this problem?

Edit:

I don't have control over given spec file. i need to generate a valid client. swagger code gen worked fine (just removed the special characters). There is no hint about this in migration guide. How to get equivalent code with new generator?

Comment: Fix your swagger to have normal names, or send a PR to openapi generator to transform `«»` to `_`.

Comment: Could it be the `"ResultList«GenericRow»":` or the :  ` "title": "ResultList«GenericRow»"` that could be in cause, in the json descriptor ? What about if you try to rewrite them `ResultList<GenericRow>` ? It seems they are taken verbatim.

Comment: what is the cause of the problem? does the spec changed? the swagger code gen produced code it seems by just removing «». All allowed (by swagger open api) characters should be handled correctly in code gen. «» might not be the only problematic characters for java (samer for any target language)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when switching from from swagger-codegen-cli to openapi-generator-cli. In my case, addding *forCodeGeneration*in Swagger Configuration like that helped:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .forCodeGeneration(true);
   }
}
```